# How do I position separate cameras in each room to show where the player is?

Tags: c#, object, unity-game-engine, camera

I've implemented player movement, as well as three different rooms. I understand how to create a first and third person camera, but how can I make three different camera views to track the player from room to room? More specifically, is there a way to zoom in on each room when the corresponding button is clicked?

[image]

So far I have a separate script attached to the main camera with this code (I know it's probably not the most efficient way, but I'm just learning Unity and C# so this is the way that makes the most sense to me):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class cameraControls : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    //private Vector3 offset;
    public bool greenRoom;
    public bool blueRoom;
    public bool purpleRoom;


    void OnGUI()
    {
        // Room 1 (Green room)
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(20, 50, 140, 40), "Green Room Camera"))
        {
            greenRoom = true;
            blueRoom = false;
            purpleRoom = false;
        }

        // Room 2 (Blue room)
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(20, 110, 140, 40), "Blue Room Camera"))
        {
            blueRoom = true;
            greenRoom = false;
            purpleRoom = false;
        }

        // Room 3 (Purple room)
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(20, 110, 140, 40), "Purple Room Camera"))
        {
            blueRoom = false;
            greenRoom = false;
            purpleRoom = true;
        }
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //offset = transform.position - player.transform.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (greenRoom == true && blueRoom == false && purpleRoom == false)
        {
        }

        if (blueRoom == true && greenRoom == false && purpleRoom == false)
        {
        }

        if (purpleRoom == true && blueRoom == false && greenRoom == false)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that by using transform.LookAt, I could set specific coordinates!